# How to test if event.target.hasClass() using angularJS and jqlite?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom-events, angularjs-ng-click, jqlite

After a click pass the event to ctrl. I want to write a conditional that will return true if the `element.target` has the class `modal-click-shield`

**Question:**

How can I use `.hasClass()` with `event.target` using angulars' `jqlite`?

**Problem:**

*Currently I'm getting a type error saying that:*

```
$scope.exitModal = function(event){
        // Return to current page when exiting the modal, via UI.
        // After state return, should set focus on the matching link.
        var target = event.target;
        console.log(target.hasClass('modal-click-shield'));
});
```

**Error:**

> TypeError: undefined is not a function

**Html:**

```
  <div class="modal-click-shield" ng-click="exitModal($event)">
     <div ui-view="pdw"  class="product-container"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: `angular.element(event.target).hasClass('modal-click-shield')`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your element from `event.target` is a regular HTMLElement, not the JQlite version. You need to do this to convert it:

```
angular.element(event.target);
```

Answer (score 13):

If you want to keep using your JS DOM element plain without use jQuery or angular:

```
event.target.classList.contains('modal-click-shield')
```

Comment: Best compatibility for Angular 1/2

Answer (score 4):

because event.target is a DOM node, not a "jQuery" object. Wrap it

```
var target = $(event.target);
```

or

```
angular.element(event.target);
```

Comment: I'm not useing jQuery.  how can I convert it to a jqlite object?

Comment: ReferenceError: $ is not defined